# Changing color of function in Clion

Tags: clion

Hi I'm having trouble changing the color of my function color. I'm using material theme and I change change almost all of the colors besides the function calls. Anyone experience this problem and know how to fix it? Is it listed under another heading? I'm currently using it for C/C++

Answer (score 0):

In "Setting | Editor | Color&Fonts| C/C++" you see the code preview. It has "from context" selection option. Just click over the function call or any other word in preview to customize the color settings.
Note! You need to "Save as" new color scheme before you start change it.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did. I can change all the other colors like precrossor directives, global variables etc. but When I tried to change the "Function" the color changes to my disired color on the preview but is not reflected even after i save and apply

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what fixed it was getting cygwin properly installed and set up. Once I did that, the highlighting options I selected showed up after the first build.